# How to display joined entries from two tables in a database as an HTML table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

Hope you all are well.

I have 3 database tables:

[image: 'Events' table with event ID, name and location] 'Events' table with event ID, name and location.

[image: 'Students' Table with StudentID, First Name, Last name, House and Year/grade] 'Students' Table with StudentID, First Name, Last name, House and Year/grade.

and [image: an 'entries' table with StudentID, and two events that they choose to enroll in.] an 'entries' table with StudentID, and two events that they choose to enroll in.

How can I create an SQL code that allows me to display an event? For example, if I wanted to display...

[image: The year 7 girl's 100m run.] The year 7 girl's 100m run.

In the form of a table similar to this one:

[image: sample table with an empty space for people to manually write times in.] sample table with an empty space for people to manually write times in.

How would I do that, so that it accepts input from the combo boxes and finds the students with this event chosen(either in the Ev1 or Ev2 field) and lists them out, when the information is spread out over 3 different tables?

Here's the code I have, but I don't think it works.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Sports Day Lineup Generator</title>
</head>

<body>

Hello! What page would you like to see?<br><br>

<form id="form2" name="form2" method="POST" action="display.php">
<select id="Year"><option value="7">Y7</option><option value="8">Y8</option><option value="9">Y9</option><option value="10">Y10</option><option value="11">Y11</option><option value="12">IB1</option><option value="13">IB2</option></select>

<select id="Gender"><option value="0">Girls</option><option value="1">Boys</option></select>

<select id="Event">
<option value="1">100m</option><option value="2 relay">100m Relay</option><option value="3">400m</option><option value="4">800m</option><option value="5">Indoor Sports</option><option value="6">High Jump</option><option value="7">Long Jump</option><option value="8">Triple Jump</option><option value="9">Shotput</option>
</select><br>
<input type="submit" value="generate">
</form>
OR <form id="form2" name="form2" method="POST" action="displayAll.php"><input type="submit" value="generate all tables"></form>
</body>
</html>
```

this is the adminPage.php, and this:

```
<?php 

//This gets all the other information from the form 
$id=$_POST['studID']; 
$event1=$_POST['event1']; 
$event2=$_POST['event2']; 

// Connects to your Database 
// require_once 'login.php';
$db_hostname = 'localhost';
$db_username = 'root';
$db_password = 'ITGS!!!';
$db_server=mysql_connect($db_hostname,$db_username,$db_password);

if(!$db_server) die("Unable to connect to MySQL" .mysql_error());

$db_database='sportsDay';

mysql_select_db($db_database,$db_server)
or die("Unable to connect to database. " .mysql_error()); 

$sql = "SELECT Entries.stID, Students.fName, Students.lName, Students.gender, Events.eventID
```

FROM Events
INNER JOIN Customers
ON Students.stID=Entries.stID; ";
    $result = $db_server->query($sql);

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table><tr><th>Name</th><th>House</th></tr>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>".$row["fName"]." ".$row["lName"]."</td><td>".$row["house"]."</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();

     ?> 

     <html>

     <body>
     </body>
     </html>
```

is my display.php.

Comment: Is your SQL query working Hanalei Ezz ? If the query working, it will be easy to create the html table. I can help when I know if the query is good enough or You need help with it too

Comment: @androidnation yes could I please have assistance with the query? I've modified it but it's still wrong.. I'm having trouble understanding how to join THREE different tables as well as use a search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hanalei, I don't know what really you want in your question, but I will assume that you need to show tables according to drop list values. So the first step would be, is to get this value into `PHP` file.

You have this `SQL` query:

```
$sql = "SELECT Entries.stID, 
Students.fName, Students.lName, Students.gender, 
Events.eventID
FROM Events INNER JOIN Customers ON Students.stID=Entries.stID; "; 
$result = $db_server->query($sql);
```

And it should be like the following where I don't see a table called `customers` and I guess you mean by that `students`. And you have an extra `;` inside the `SQL` select query:

```
$sql = "SELECT Entries.stID, 
Students.fName, Students.lName, Students.gender, 
Events.eventID
FROM Events INNER JOIN Students ON Students.stID=Entries.stID"; 
$result = $db_server->query($sql);
```

Now, inside your `HTML` Form you have some errors, where you have an ID for each drop list, but server takes name tag value, so instead of this line:

```
<select id="Year">
<option value="7">Y7</option>
<option value="8">Y8</option>
<option value="9">Y9</option>
<option value="10">Y10</option>
<option value="11">Y11</option>
<option value="12">IB1</option>
<option value="13">IB2</option>
</select>
```

It should be like this:

```
<select id="Year" name="Year">
<option value="7">Y7</option>
<option value="8">Y8</option>
<option value="9">Y9</option>
<option value="10">Y10</option>
<option value="11">Y11</option>
<option value="12">IB1</option>
<option value="13">IB2</option>
</select>
```

I've added `name="Year"` and now the `$_POST['Year']` will take a proper value.

Add a `name` tag to each drop list, and you will be able to send them into your PHP file `display.php` as:

```
$year = $_POST['Year'];
$gender = $_POST['Gender'];
$event = $_POST['Event'];

$sql = "SELECT Entries.stID, 
Students.fName, Students.lName, Students.gender, 
Events.eventID
FROM Events INNER JOIN Students ON Students.stID=Entries.stID
WHERE Students.year = '.$year.' AND Student.gender = '.$gender.'"; 
$result = $db_server->query($sql);
```

You first table isn't connected to the second one with a Foreign Key so we can't make a JOIN to get where all those with a specific year and gender should be to do their event.

And you should consider start learning `mysqli_` or `PHP-PDO` for more secured data.

I hope I understood what you where asking for, and you can email for more help, if this doesn't help you.

Comment: hello! thank you sooo much for this. unfortunately it does seem that my SQL code was wrong, and i fixed the code to make it do what i want. is it okay if i email you and ask further questions? i really appreciate your help, sir/madam. :) thank you. @androidnation

Comment: My name is Ali and here is my email: alexmhd9090@gmail.com and you email me whenever you want